# ESP 32 doesn't connect to wifi

Tags: wifi, esp32, arduino-c++

I cant connect my ESP32 to my wifi, but i can connect to my cellphone router. I made a simple print to show which code it returns, and i get over and over WL_IDLE_STATUS.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* meuSSID = "asdfgh";
const char* meuPASS = "12345678";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(meuSSID , meuPASS);

  int status = WiFi.status();
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("status:");
    Serial.println(status);

    Serial.print("ip:");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());

    Serial.println("Conectando...");
    status = WiFi.status();
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Oi");
  delay(1000);
}
```

I tried to put `WiFi.setMinSecurity(WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK);`, but no sucess.

Output (my wifi)

```
status:0
ip:0.0.0.0
24:6F:28:B0:28:6C
Conectando...
status:0
ip:0.0.0.0
24:6F:28:B0:28:6C
Conectando...

(...)
```

Output (my cellphone)

```
status:6
ip:0.0.0.0
24:6F:28:B0:28:6C
Conectando...
status:6
ip:192.168.43.1
24:6F:28:B0:28:6C
Conectando...
192.168.43.1
```

Comment: Are you sure the wifi network you're trying to connect to is 2.4GHz? The ESP32 doesn't support 5GHz networks. If you run a [wifi scanner](https://blog.robberg.net/wifi-scanner-with-esp32/), do you see the network you're trying to connect to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in my router configuration and its was blocking my ESP32 MAC so i just add another mac rule and now it connects.